# C++ read binary file char by char

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles

I have an assignment of saving some objects data in a specific order of its data members, I'll try to simplfy . Consider this Base class constructor from a binary file. (Please note that it was not my choice to use char *) .

```
Base(ifstream & in_file) {
    int n;
    in_file.read((char *)&n, sizeof(n));
    m_var = new char[n + 1];
    in_file.read(m_var, n);
    m_var[n] = '\0';
    in_file.read((char *)&m_intvar, sizeof(m_intvar));
}
```

It has to initialize m_var (char *) and another integer variable. This code works, though it **requiers** to save the length of the char * for me to allocate the memory.

The problem starts here. I was instructed not to save the size of the string, but to only enter a `\n` after each value i write to the file. So I need some how to read the file, and get the string until the `\n` character.

I was thinking about reading char by char, but couldn't find a way to do it, I assume there is an istream function that offers that. Some similar function to `>>`  of a text file would also be good I assume.

Comment: How about [std::ifstream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)?

Comment: @ForceBru As far as I know it's an operator for text files?

Comment: cppreference.com is your friend: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: How about `std::getline()`?

Comment: Note that a separator like `'\n'` doesn't work on truly binary data, it can only work on text data (the file might be open in binary mode, and might have binary data in other portions of the file)

Answer (score 0):

After consulting cppreference.com I end up as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(std::istream & in_file) { // NOTE: changed to istream to allow reading from any stream not just files
        in_file.read((char *)&n, sizeof(n));
        char buffer[1024];
        in_file.get(buffer, sizeof(buffer), '\n');
        size_t gcount = in_file.gcount();
        if (in_file.get() != '\n')
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("binary string to long"); // you may want to implement a loop here using peek() to check for newline
        }
        m_var = new char[gcount];
        std::copy(buffer, buffer + gcount, m_var);
    }

    Base(int num, const char* strg)
        : n(num)
        , m_var(strdup(strg))
    {
    }

    bool operator == (const Base& rhs)
    {
        return n == rhs.n && strcpy(m_var, rhs.m_var);
    }

    void write(std::ostream& out)
    {
        out.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
        out.write(m_var, strlen(m_var));
        out.write("\n", 1);
    }


    int n;
    char* m_var = nullptr;

    ~Base()
    {
        delete m_var;
    }



};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Base b1(10, "Hello Word!");
    {
        std::ofstream out("testfile.bin");
        b1.write(out);
    }
    std::ifstream in("testfile.bin");
    Base b2(in);

    if (b1 == b2)
    {
        std::cout << "read ok!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "read failed!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4 years later but I was having a similar problem and found this post.
You can read char by char as you mention, with a loop.

```
int i;
for(i=0;;i++){
    cout<<i;
    in_file.read(&buffer[i],sizeof(char));
    if buffer[i]=='\n') break; 
}
```

The only problem with the code I came up is it saves the '\n'. But you can and should replace it to the NULL char '\0' after having found the new line '\n'.
(buffer[i]=='\0')

Please correct me if I am mistaken.